# Last digits number theory. $7^{9999}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

i have looked at/practiced several methods for solving ex: $7^{9999}$. i have looked at techniques using a)modulas/congruence b) binomial theorem c) totient/congruence d) cyclicity.

my actual desire would be a start to finish approach using totient/congruence. i have figured out how to work the individual steps but not how to combine them and in what order to be able to solve any "end digits" questions.

Comment: How many final digits do you seek?

Comment: 1 - 3 is what i would like to be able to solve

Comment: Generally you use Euler's theorem to reduce the exponent modulo $\,\phi(10^n)\,$ or $\,\lambda(10^n),\,$ where $\,n\,$ is the number of final digits. Any simplifications after that are that are generally ad-hoc, depending on the specifics of  the problem.

Comment: ex: i can find ϕ(1000)=400, but do not know ad-hoc steps to follow after that? thks

Comment: Also, you could choose generators of the multiplicative group, and build tables rules, etc. For example, John Conway and I devised a simple way to do this for $\,\Bbb Z/100^{\,*},$ which makes it very easy to compute powers and roots/logs etc. I call them the lucky $7$-$11$ logs (the generators  $7$ and $11$ prove very convenient).

Comment: is this the same as the cyclicity tables?

Answer (score 5):

Note:

$7^4$ ends in $1$

So,
$7^8$, $7^{12}$, $7^{16}$ all end in $1$.

So, $7^{9996}$ ends in $1$. And $7^3$ ends in $3$. So, the answer is $3$

I have used the fact that
$$
\phi(10) = 4
$$
where $\phi$ is the totient function.

---

*Note: Added in response to OP's comment*

If we want the last two digits, we note that $\phi(1000)=400$. So
$$
9999 = 9600 + 399$$
So
$$
7^{9999} \equiv 7^{399} \mod 1000
$$
Since $399$ is 1 less than $400$ we can calculate the answer easily. I will show both the long way and the short way.

Long way which works for any power (not all calculations shown):

We divide by two each time to get
$$
399 = 199+200 \\
199= 99 + 100 \\
88= 49 + 50 \\
49= 24 + 25\\
25 = 12 + 13 \\
13 = 6 + 7 \\
7 = 3+ 4\\
3 = 1 +2 
$$
Now  (all mod 1000)
$$
7^1 = 7,~~~ 7^2 = 49\\
7^3 = 7 \cdot 49 = 343, ~~~7^4 = 49 \cdot 49 = 401\\
7^6 = 343 \times 343 = 649~~~ 7^7 = 343 \cdot 401 = 543
$$ and so on.

You can also find $7^{-1} \mod 1000$ as $143$.
So the last 3 digits are **143**

Comment: You can use the same idea if you want more digits...$\phi(100) = 100 \times(1/2) \times (4/5)=40$. So $7^{40}$ ends in $01, though finding more digits get to be tedius.

Comment: hmm... Why the down vote?

Comment: i do follow this, however if asked for last 3 digits how would i proceed? i understand ϕ(1000)=400 but do not know next steps. thanks

Comment: Well...9999 = 9600 + 399, so you need $7^{399} \mod 100$. i assume you know how to calculate $7^{399}$ with just 9 multiplications. If not, ask

Comment: i followed your first answer and understand 9999 = 9600 + 399 but you lost me at 7^399 mod 100. where am i going from here to find last 1,2 or 3 digits?

Comment: I meant 1000... see my updated post.

Comment: this makes sense, i need to work through it myself a bit more but i am at least following your thinking. thanks for your time and effort

Comment: You are welcome. If you noticed that $7^4 \mod 1 \mod 100$ you will show you don't need to go all the way to $400$, but $7^{40} \equiv 1\mod 1000$ and cut your work quite a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Find the last three digits of $7^{9999}$

Solution:
By *Euler’s theorem* 
$(7, 10000)$ are relatively prime therefore $$7 ^ {\phi (1000)} \equiv 1 \pmod {1000}$$

$\phi (1000) = 1000 (1-1/2) (1-1/5)$ {$2$ & $5$ are the only prime divisors of $1000$}$= 400.$

Hence $$7^{400} \equiv 1 \pmod {1000}$$
Also $$(7^{400}) ^{25}\equiv 1^{25} \pmod {1000}$$

Hence $$7^{10000}\equiv 1 \pmod {1000}\tag 1$$
We know
$$\begin{align}
1001 \equiv 1 &\pmod {1000}\\
\implies 1 \equiv 1001 &\pmod {1000}\\
\implies 1\equiv 7 \times 143 &\pmod {1000}\tag 2\\
\end{align}$$
By $1$ and $2$ we get
$$7^{10000}\equiv 7 \times 143 \pmod {1000}$$
$$7^{9999}\equiv 143 \pmod {1000}$$
Hence the last three digits for $7^{9999}$ are $$\bbox[border:2px solid red]{143}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $7^2=49\equiv 9 \mod 10$, since $9^2=81 \equiv 1 \mod 10$, we have that
$$
7^4\equiv 1 \mod 10
$$
Now notice that $4 \mid 9996$ because $4$ divides $96$ (a number is divisible by $4$ iff its last two digits are divisible by $4$). That leaves us with a $7^3$ remaining which we know that $7^3\equiv 3 \mod 10$.

So that means that 
$$
7^{9999}\equiv 7^3 \equiv 1\cdot 3=3 \mod 10
$$
This means the last digit of $7^{9999}$ is $3$.

Comment: i follow you did 7^9996 * 7^3 but i do not understand what you thinking is behind the first line you wrote: 7^2=49≡9mod10, since 9^2=81≡1mod10, we have that
7^4≡1mod10

Comment: $7^4=7^2\cdot 7^2\equiv 9\cdot 9=81\equiv 1 \mod 10$.

Comment: ok, a quick check of my underwood dudley book lets me see you are only using last digit, thnks

Comment: You only asked for the last digit as far as I can tell. If you wanted the last two digits, you would work $\mod 100$, the last three, $\mod 1000$ and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

calculate the congruence class of $999\bmod\phi(10^n)$ (call it $c$). then the last n digits are the last n digits of $7^c$.

Use $\phi(10^n)=4(10)^{n-1}$

For 1 digit: $999\equiv3\bmod4$ so it's $3$

for 2 digits $999\equiv39\bmod 40$ so its $43$

for 3 digits $999\equiv 199 \mod400$ so its $143$

for more than 3 Euler saves you no time. You can try calculating Charmicael's Lambda which is $2^{n-2}\cdot5^{n-1}$for $n\geq3$