# A question from a past BMO exam, on modulo

Tags: modular-arithmetic, contest-math, problem-solving

If the last three digits of the number $7^{400}$ are 001 find the last three digits of the number $7^{9999}$.

Guys, I tried working out this question today, however to no success. I tried using modulo, to work it out and also tried to find a motive, however, I could not find one. Can you guys please help me?

Thanking you in advance

Michael

Comment: See [here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-last-two-digits-of-7-9999) and [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623670/last-digits-number-theory-79999).

Comment: @michael , sadly points are pointless mathematically. HINT: Euler's totient theorem + modular multiplicative inverse.